# Adgamer interstitial ad doesn't show

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement AdGamer SDK in my Unity game. I'm calling `AdGamer.InterstitialAds.Show()` but it doesn't show anything. Please help

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be for several reasons:

- The interstitial hasn't yet been *loaded*. So, check `AdGamer.InterstitialAd.IsReady()` before trying to show an interstitial ad
- The SDK hasn't yet been *initialized*. Make sure to call `AdGamer.InitWithGameToken(YOUR_GAME_TOKEN);` before calling anything else in the AdGamer SDK. For example, you can do that in `Awake()` method in a script which you put on some `GameObject` in the first scene your game loads. Or you could create a static method with the attribute `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]`
  to make it run at game launch before anything else. It can be in any script and there you'd initialize the SDK. The game token you get when you register your game in the AdGamer publisher console.
- The initialization of the SDK may take several seconds (e.g. it may need to auto-update), so if you're trying to show an interstitial very early (right at game launch, before the starting screen) the call will likely fail. For such cases you may want to check `AdGamer.IsInitialized` before doing anything else.

```cs
   // in any script

   [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
   public static void InitializeAdGamerBeforeEverything()
   {
       AdGamer.InitWithGameToken(YOUR_GAME_TOKEN);
   }

   // elsewhere in code

   if (AdGamer.IsInitialized && AdGamer.InterstitialAd.IsReady())
   {
       AdGamer.InterstitialAds.Show();
   }
```

- There is no internet connection or some firewall or other settings on your machine prevent the game from connecting with AdGamer servers

Note that the *"no_fill" case doesn't exist* in AdGamer: it should return at least a cross-promo ad even if no commercial ad is available in your country at the moment.

Also, please be sure to check the [SDK documentation](http://files.adgamer.com.s3.amazonaws.com/sdk/unity/documentation/AdGamer_UnitySDK_Guide.pdf) (it also comes as a PDF file inside the unitypackage)